# jQuery click() not firing on tap until hover state is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an element on my page which I've targeted with jQuery to run a small function on `click()`.

This element is styled with CSS, it's `opacity` is set to `0.5`, and then on hover, that's changed to `1.0`.

I've had some issues in the past when changing the `opacity`, or `display` properties of an element on hover, to make things needed to be 'tapped' twice on touch screen devices.

For example, if I had an anchor tab wrapped around a `div`, which on hover, was changing the `opacity` or `display` properties of elements inside the `div`, to get redirected to the anchor `href` I'd have to tap the element twice.

I'm thinking this might be the same sort of issue. I think I could solve this issue by listening for the `click()` and `tap()` event, but then I'd need to load jQuery Mobile, which I don't really want to do.

*In short: On some mobile devices, I have to click the element once, which puts the element into a hover state, and then again for the jQuery `click()` event to fire.*

**This is the jQuery I'm using, wrapped inside DOM ready:**

```
$('#scroll-down').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    page.on("scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove", function() {
        page.stop();
    });
    page.animate({
        scrollTop: viewportHeight + 2
    }, 1000, function() {
        page.off("scroll mousedown wheel DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup touchmove");
    });
    return false;
});
```

It scrolls down the height of the viewport, plus 2 pixels.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add your code into your question please

Comment: Please have a look at : http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes

:hover may not be the ideal thing to use in case of mobile devices.

Comment: please share what u have done so far

Comment: Are you using `.click()` or `.on('click', ...)` because for mobiles the 2nd one is better.

Comment: I'll try the `on('click')` method now, and get back to you. I've also added my jQuery.

Comment: I'm waiting on BrowserStack to get back online before I can test the above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Aaron suggested, using `.on('click')` seems to have fixed the issue.